# Getting children children in sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I'm trying to list items which have a set template on the parent page in Sitecore. So far I can do it for the children but I also want to include the children's children, i.e. anything under the parent if it has the chosen template it will work, this is my code in the c# file:

```
lvThing.DataSource = context.Children.Where(x => x.TemplateName == "cool    template").ToList<Item>();
lvThing.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want the items below the children, you can use the item.Axes.GetDescendants() method to get all items below the context item.

Your code then should look like this:

```
contextItem.Axes.GetDescendants().Where(x => x.TemplateName == "cool    template").ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but getting an error, using: lvThing.DataSource = contextItem.Axes.GetDescendants().Where(x => x.TemplateName == "cool template").ToList<Item>();

Comment: ah, got to to work by changing contextitem to context. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: I'd be careful using GetDescendants it can be pretty expensive.

Comment: Given the additional filtering applied, you might consider contextItem.Axes.SelectItems(string query), which lets you use a sitecore query executed relative to the contextItem. (ex: contextItem.Axes.SelectItems("descendant-or-self::*[@@templatename='cool    template']")